# Get icon 128*128 File type C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I need to get the icon of a file type doc  or txt

It's size should be 128*128 and be saved as an png or ico file in good quality.

I used

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"d:\\1.txt");
pictureBox1.Image = ico.ToBitmap();
```

and save the image from the pictureBox1, but that size is 32*32.

I really want a size 128*128.

How can I do that?

Comment: maybe this can help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16178/IconLib-Icons-Unfolded-MultiIcon-and-Windows-Vista

Comment: not open file doc only exe i need file type doc ,txt @TomerKlein

Comment: o.k, Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701263/get-the-icon-for-a-given-extension or:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29137/Get-Registered-File-Types-and-Their-Associated-Ico

Comment: not Good quality @TomerKlein

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no icon-size 128x128 available from the Shell API [SHGetImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx). The sizes range from the Win95 era of 16x16 and 32x32 via XP's 48x48 and finally Vista that added the 256x256 size.

To get a png file from any of the available icon sizes I followed the [blog How do I get a high resolution icon for a file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/20/10490951.aspx) from [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen). I ported his code to c# where I borrowed pieces from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701380/578411).

To follow Raymond's article here are the main two functions you need:

```
    int GetIconIndex(string pszFile)
    {
        SHFILEINFO sfi = new SHFILEINFO();
        Shell32.SHGetFileInfo(pszFile
            , 0
            , ref sfi
            , (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(sfi)
            , (uint)  (SHGFI.SysIconIndex | SHGFI.LargeIcon | SHGFI.UseFileAttributes));
        return sfi.iIcon;
    }

    // 256*256
    IntPtr GetJumboIcon(int iImage)
    {
        IImageList spiml = null;
        Guid guil = new Guid(IID_IImageList2);//or IID_IImageList

        Shell32.SHGetImageList(Shell32.SHIL_JUMBO, ref guil, ref spiml);
        IntPtr hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
        spiml.GetIcon(iImage, Shell32.ILD_TRANSPARENT | Shell32.ILD_IMAGE, ref hIcon); //

        return hIcon;
    }
```

The method GetIconIndex calls into the native [SHGetFileIfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the icon index for the file (or extension) you provided in the name parameter.

To get the actual icon the method `GetJumboIcon` calls the native [SHGetImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx) with a size attribute.

To let it all work you combine the calls like so:

```
IntPtr hIcon = GetJumboIcon(GetIconIndex("*.txt"));

// from native to managed
using (Icon ico = (Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(hIcon).Clone())
{
    // save to file (or show in a picture box)
    ico.ToBitmap().Save("txticon.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
Shell32.DestroyIcon(hIcon); // don't forget to cleanup
```

To get an 48x48 icon you can extend the code with this method:

```
    // 48X48
    IntPtr GetXLIcon(int iImage)
    {
        IImageList spiml = null;
        Guid guil = new Guid(IID_IImageList);//or IID_IImageList

        Shell32.SHGetImageList(Shell32.SHIL_EXTRALARGE, ref guil, ref spiml);
        IntPtr hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
        spiml.GetIcon(iImage, Shell32.ILD_TRANSPARENT | Shell32.ILD_IMAGE, ref hIcon); //

        return hIcon;
    }
```

Due to interaction with unmanaged code you need to compile the project with the /unsafe option enabled. You can set that from visual studio by changing the project  properties, goto to the Build tab and put a checkmark for the **Allow unsafe code** option. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233759/what-is-the-actual-function-of-the-c-sharp-project-setting-allow-unsafe-code) why that is needed and [here is the official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx)

#### Native wrapper

To call the native win32 api the functions and structures are wrapped in a static class that you need to include as well in your project. Most of those wrappers and the structures can be found at [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetImageList.html)

```
const string IID_IImageList = "46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950";
const string IID_IImageList2 = "192B9D83-50FC-457B-90A0-2B82A8B5DAE1";

public static class Shell32
{

    public const int SHIL_LARGE =0x0;
    public const int SHIL_SMALL =0x1;
    public const int SHIL_EXTRALARGE =0x2;
    public const int SHIL_SYSSMALL =0x3;
    public const int SHIL_JUMBO = 0x4;
    public const int SHIL_LAST = 0x4;

    public const int ILD_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000001;
    public const int ILD_IMAGE = 0x00000020;

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#727")]
    public extern static int SHGetImageList(int iImageList, ref Guid riid, ref IImageList ppv);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DestroyIcon", SetLastError = true)]
    public static unsafe extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SHGetIDListFromObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object iUnknown, out IntPtr ppidl);

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
        string pszPath,
        uint dwFileAttributes,
        ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
        uint cbFileInfo,
        uint uFlags
    );
}
```

#### Native structures

```
[Flags]
enum SHGFI : uint
{
    /// <summary>get icon</summary>
    Icon = 0x000000100,
    /// <summary>get display name</summary>
    DisplayName = 0x000000200,
    /// <summary>get type name</summary>
    TypeName = 0x000000400,
    /// <summary>get attributes</summary>
    Attributes = 0x000000800,
    /// <summary>get icon location</summary>
    IconLocation = 0x000001000,
    /// <summary>return exe type</summary>
    ExeType = 0x000002000,
    /// <summary>get system icon index</summary>
    SysIconIndex = 0x000004000,
    /// <summary>put a link overlay on icon</summary>
    LinkOverlay = 0x000008000,
    /// <summary>show icon in selected state</summary>
    Selected = 0x000010000,
    /// <summary>get only specified attributes</summary>
    Attr_Specified = 0x000020000,
    /// <summary>get large icon</summary>
    LargeIcon = 0x000000000,
    /// <summary>get small icon</summary>
    SmallIcon = 0x000000001,
    /// <summary>get open icon</summary>
    OpenIcon = 0x000000002,
    /// <summary>get shell size icon</summary>
    ShellIconSize = 0x000000004,
    /// <summary>pszPath is a pidl</summary>
    PIDL = 0x000000008,
    /// <summary>use passed dwFileAttribute</summary>
    UseFileAttributes = 0x000000010,
    /// <summary>apply the appropriate overlays</summary>
    AddOverlays = 0x000000020,
    /// <summary>Get the index of the overlay in the upper 8 bits of the iIcon</summary>
    OverlayIndex = 0x000000040,
}   

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public const int NAMESIZE = 80;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
};


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS
{
    public int cbSize;
    public IntPtr himl;
    public int i;
    public IntPtr hdcDst;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
    public int xBitmap;    // x offest from the upperleft of bitmap
    public int yBitmap;    // y offset from the upperleft of bitmap
    public int rgbBk;
    public int rgbFg;
    public int fStyle;
    public int dwRop;
    public int fState;
    public int Frame;
    public int crEffect;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct IMAGEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hbmImage;
    public IntPtr hbmMask;
    public int Unused1;
    public int Unused2;
    public RECT rcImage;
}
[ComImportAttribute()]
[GuidAttribute("46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IImageList
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int Add(
    IntPtr hbmImage,
    IntPtr hbmMask,
    ref int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int ReplaceIcon(
    int i,
    IntPtr hicon,
    ref int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetOverlayImage(
    int iImage,
    int iOverlay);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Replace(
    int i,
    IntPtr hbmImage,
    IntPtr hbmMask);

    [PreserveSig]
    int AddMasked(
    IntPtr hbmImage,
    int crMask,
    ref int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Draw(
    ref IMAGELISTDRAWPARAMS pimldp);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Remove(
int i);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIcon(
    int i,
    int flags,
    ref IntPtr picon);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageInfo(
    int i,
    ref IMAGEINFO pImageInfo);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Copy(
    int iDst,
    IImageList punkSrc,
    int iSrc,
    int uFlags);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Merge(
    int i1,
    IImageList punk2,
    int i2,
    int dx,
    int dy,
    ref Guid riid,
    ref IntPtr ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Clone(
    ref Guid riid,
    ref IntPtr ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageRect(
    int i,
    ref RECT prc);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIconSize(
    ref int cx,
    ref int cy);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetIconSize(
    int cx,
    int cy);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageCount(
ref int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetImageCount(
    int uNewCount);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetBkColor(
    int clrBk,
    ref int pclr);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetBkColor(
    ref int pclr);

    [PreserveSig]
    int BeginDrag(
    int iTrack,
    int dxHotspot,
    int dyHotspot);

    [PreserveSig]
    int EndDrag();

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragEnter(
    IntPtr hwndLock,
    int x,
    int y);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragLeave(
    IntPtr hwndLock);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragMove(
    int x,
    int y);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDragCursorImage(
    ref IImageList punk,
    int iDrag,
    int dxHotspot,
    int dyHotspot);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragShowNolock(
    int fShow);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDragImage(
    ref POINT ppt,
    ref POINT pptHotspot,
    ref Guid riid,
    ref IntPtr ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetItemFlags(
    int i,
    ref int dwFlags);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetOverlayImage(
    int iOverlay,
    ref int piIndex);
};
```

Comment: This is an outstanding answer, there are countless other partially functioning answers and this by far is the most thorough and straightforward I have seen. For a single file example of code see https://gist.github.com/bruceburge/adc84840920ed262669353dd64ffd9f2