# Enterprise Enterprise.windows.win32.win32

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when using `Enterprise.Windows.Win32.Win32.GetLargeIcon`. Which dll do I need to import to resolve it?

```
public Icon ObjectIcon
{
    get
    {                
        if (_objectIcon == null)
        {
            _objectIcon = Enterprise.Windows.Win32.Win32.GetLargeIcon(_filePathAndName);
        }

        return _objectIcon;
    }
}
```

This is a piece of code in the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322247/how-can-i-embed-any-file-type-into-microsoft-word-using-openxml-2-0)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know where that namespace comes from but I expect its functionality is similar to what I described in [Get icon 128*128 File type C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530403/578411)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_objectIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(_filePathAndName);
```