# .NET C#: How to get Windows default "vector" icon for file type

Tags: c#, .net, windows, icons

I want to retrieve the default icon Windows Explorer is using for a file type (i.e. TXT file).

I have already implemented http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530403/1572750 (using `GetJumboIcon()` method which delivers a 256x256 icon) and it is almost perfect.

On comparing Windows Explorer with the result though it shows that it is still not the same:
[image]

It seems to me Windows (from v10 on) use vector icons. Also the icon for PDFs (I see the SumatraPDF icon) looks like it would be a vector image.

Is there a way to get a handle on this image?

Thanks
Soko

PS: I still find it a strange that there is no better way in 2023 than using unsafe code to get this info from Windows?!

Comment: Sidenote regarding your PS: Dotnet isn't a windows api replacement so don't expect getting everything from the framework. That might have been the target in the early days but was buried fast. Since the advent of core its even more unlikely to get such things as its tries to be OS agnostic. You might ask if this is a problem someone else should also have had earlier and maybe created a nuget for this. Possible but i don't know.

Comment: You may have more luck with `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage()` E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751747/extract-thumbnail-for-any-file-in-windows

Comment: @Ralf: Thats true... .NET7 (which I use) is not about Windows anymore. Thanks for the nuget hint.

Comment: @AlexK.: Looks promising. My issue with that is though the necessity of a file with the type/extension on the hard drive. The signature of the method I need should look like this: 
`public static Image GetDefaultIcon(string fileExtension)` with `fileExtension` being `*.txt` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You mention SumatraPDF Icon as looking vector but same as all others is simply Vista Image

[image]

[image]